# How to test if, in a list of scores, my top scores are significantly different then the rest?

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, image-processing

I have a data library consisting of approx. 24'000 3D images, against which I want to run some image similarity comparisons.
I have one image, and run it against my whole data library to find similar images.

Now I want to know if my top score or top scores are really significantly higher than the scores below them. 
What I mean by that is that if I have two lists,

A = [0.9, 0.13, 0.12, 0.11, 0.10, 0.09]

B = [0.55, 0.54, 0.53, 0.52, 0.51, 0.50]

I can probably say that my top hit in A of 0.9 is significant, whereas in B, my top hit of 0.55 is not much better than the others. My problem now is how do I quantify that?

What I have considered so far:

- I have tried a
  simple one-sample t-test, (comparing every score to the mean of the scores below them) and permuation t-tests. The problem there is the huge size of 25'000 scores
  which will give me very small std error, and thus t-tests result in high p-values for every single score.
- I have thought about running t-tests for every score compared to just the immediate 50 scores or so below them, but that seems a little random to me.
- I have also looked at effect size measures, and calculated cohen's d, which, if I interpret this correctly, is a measure of how many standard deviations my value is away from the mean. I am unsure how to interpret this as compared to a p-value. The cohen's d value ranges from -1.04 to +29 in one specific example.

Is there a recommended method to do this? Any different approaches that I could try?

In the end, I want to be able to say that yes, this image with the highest score is much better than the others that the hit is meaningful, or that, while this is my top hit image, all other scores are similar and thus the top hit is not meaningful.

Comment: How many lists do you have? How many elements in each list? Are you trying to find extreme values in each list?

Comment: I have one score per image in my data library, so about 24'000 elements per list. I'll just be looking at one list at a time, so I do not need to compare different lists.
And yes, I would like to be able to find out if the highest scores in my list are extreme values.

Comment: Given your huge sample size inferential statistics may not be a good option as you have already figured out. You could simply transform all the values into a z-score and consider a value extreme if its z-score is >=3 or >=4 or more.